# Error kex_exchange_identification occurs when attempting to ssh over local network because of iptables entry

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables, vpn, nordvpn

When I attempt to connect to a machine via open ssh over a local network I get the following error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 192.168.1.39 port 22
```

This appears to be because of the iptables entries that I have set to the machine.  When I allow all traffic on iptables then I can ssh just fine.  But when my vpn sets rules to the iptables I am not able to connect.

When the iptables are set to the following I am not able to ssh successfully:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target  prot opt source            destination 
..........
ACCEPT  all  --  192.168.1.0/24    anywhere   cstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT  all  --  192.168.1.0/24    anywhere   cstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT  udp  --  192.168.1.0/24    anywhere   udp dpt:51280
ACCEPT  all  --  192.168.1.0/24    anywhere   cstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
..........
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target  prot opt source     destination 
..........
ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere   192.168.1.0/24 
ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere   192.168.1.0/24 
ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere   192.168.1.0/24  
..........
```

When the iptables are set to the following I am able to ssh successfully:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT(policy ACCEPT)
```

The ip of the machine that I am connecting to is 192.168.1.39/24 and the machine that I am connecting from is 192.168.1.189/24.  So they are both on the same 192.168.1.0 network (the iptables rule should ACCEPT the connection).

I also tried adding a rule to allow all connections to that that PC but this did not resolve the issue.

The iptable entries are set by NordVPN client (to remove the entries I just disable NordVPN). I tried reinstalling the latest version of NordVPN from the aur package but this did not resolve the issue.  But obviously I want to have this running fine with NordVPN

I know that this has something to do with the iptables but I am having trouble trying to find the precise cause (im not an expert at networking but those entries above look fine) or how to fix it.

This network is just a home network.  Before it used to work fine (same pcs, same vpn, same ...) but my router just broke so i am using a new one (asus rt-ac68u) which is when the problem has started occuring. 
 I also had a look at my router settings just to see if there was anything that could explain this further but did not find anything.

Also if I turn off the vpn on 192.168.1.39 but turn on the vpn on 192.168.1.189 (which has the same iptables rules) then I am able to ssh to 192.168.1.39.  But if I turn the vpn on for both machines then I cannot ssh.

In summary

- Client (192.168.1.189) cannot ssh to Server (192.168.1.39) when servers NordVPN is on.
- Client can ssh to Server when servers NordVPN is off.
- Client can ssh to Server when clients NordVPN is off.
- Error appears to be related to Servers iptable entries

  - Adding catch all rule to Server iptable does not appear to resolve problem
- Change to network which may be related is a new router (Asus RT-AC68U) but I cannot identify any problem with its setup

Im a bit stumped on how to proceed.  Can anyone help?

Thankyou

EDIT  - I am continuing to look into this but I dont think there is much more that I can add.  I will update if there is anything else i think that I may find useful

1. In case people were thinking that the problem could be NordVPN instead of the iptables I did set the Chain INPUT policy to accept when NordVPN was on and the SSH worked fine.  So I think that it is definitely something I have messed up on the ip tables